# Excel warns "this workbook contains links" even with a new blank workbook

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I have an xlam file using both VBA and Power Query codes. I also link to an .XLAM addin to call certain UDFs and macros.

Recently Excel has given me the message "This workbook contains links to one or more external sources that could be unsafe" when I open this file.

[image]

I have tried:

1. Removing all links in Edit Links
2. Disabling the warning in "Startup Prompt" of Edit Links
3. Making sure there are no links in all sheets'formulas, conditional formattings and data validation
4. I have no charts so no links there

But none of these options worked.

I also tried to open a new blank workbook and the warning message is still there!

So I disabled the link to the Add-in In Excel Options - Add-Ins and yes, no more annoying message after that for the blank workbook.

But after I connect back to the add-in, the message comes back.

[image]

The add-in is stored in C:\OneDrive\XJ15 Macros\Live\Freelensia Macros.xlam

Why would this create issues with Link Warning message, even though I have opened a new blank workbook, and I turned off the Startup Prompt for Links?

Comment: It sounds like the add-in itself is linked to an external source (outside of itself). That is why you disable it the message goes away. Did you create the add-in (or is it from a trusted source)? If not then, it could be doing something you don't want.

Comment: Thanks @IamNerd2000, the macro is just a collection of UDFs and sub-procedures. Are you saying one of these macros refer to an outside file? Highly unlikely but I will check. Thanks!

Comment: You should also check if the addin is referencing any other addins or templates. That could be causing the problem as well.